# Drilldown Highmaps for Australia

Tags: highcharts, highmaps

Currently highmaps only have drilldown maps for USA. Is there anyone had made them for Australia or anyone have any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use correct map and prepare data, based on codes as in the america demo.